# Why is Kernel method looked up only when `send` is used?

Tags: ruby

I should be able to call `Kernel` methods on every object, and method `format` is defined on `Kernel`. Why is `method_missing` invoked on `Kernel` with the third example?

```
class A
  def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
    if meth == :foo
      puts 'ok'
    elsif meth == :format
      puts 'ok'
    end
  end
end

a = A.new
a.foo           # => ok
a.send(:foo)    # => ok
a.format        # => ok
a.send(:format) # => too few arguments (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because `Kernel#format` is a private method. When you call it using `send`, which means you are calling it without an explicit receiver, the defined method is called, and argument error is raised. When you call it with an explicit receiver, the method is not found because the defined one is private, and so `method_missing` is invoked.

Comment: Changed accepted answer to this one, as it actually explains the `send` vs. direct call mismatch better.